# How to add columns and lines next to a matrix with microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Take a look at the picture I've uploaded:
[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Rbr.png)

As you can see, over the matrix a line of numbers appears. Those numbers are exactly over each column of the matrix. Also, to the left of the matrix, another set of numbers appears. Those numbers are exactly to the left of each line of the matrix.
My question is: is it possible to do just that with Word? If yes, how?

Comment: (1) Please post text as text, if possible.   (2) When you do post images, please don’t pad them.   (3) You say “left”,  but I see “right”.

Answer (score 1):

In the Word 2016, you can use Insert | Table. Select rows count as your matrix rows + 1, and columns count as your matrix columns + 3.
When you stay anywhere in your table, toggle on Layout | View Gridlines, then select your table by Layout | Select | Table and clear its border with Design | Borders | No Border. Make the 1-st and 1 before last columns as narrow as possible and set their borders to imitate the matrix lines:
[Your matrix in the Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOXqC.png), ["Editing" mode when View Gridlines is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQkaW.png), [Cell properties settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWQhw.png)

Comment: It's a funny way of solving the problem. Did you do yourself before?

Comment: Not, but sometimes I work with table data and have to format them for presentation, so I solved similar issues.

Comment: To make a column more narrow, select it (cells) and from the selection's context menu select Table Properties... In opened dialog select the Cell tab and click Options button. In new dialog uncheck the 'Same as whole table' and set Top, Bottom, Left, Right fields to 0. Then you can shift the column by buttons (marked by arrows) or set width in the first dialog in tab Column (3-rd picture).

Answer (score 1):

In word 365 the buttons to add rows are not there anymore but typing:  \matrix(1&1&1&1@1&1&1&1@1&1&1&1@1&1&1&1)
Will give you a 4x4 matrix populated with 1's that you can edit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've recalled another maybe much more better* solution for matrices: in Word, select Insert | Equation | Insert New Equation. Then when your new equation is selected and the Design tab on the Word's Ribbon is activated, select Matrix | Empty 2 by 2 Matrix in Brackets. From the matrix context menu of your matrix, insert rows and columns to your matrix.

* I do not know how to add row and column numbers outside the matrix. Again, I can suggest solution: insert data in your matrix, then make screenshot from your document using standard Windows Snipping Tool, select only your matrix and insert it back to Word as picture. After that, for this picture from the context menu call Size and Position, in opened dialog in the Text Wrapping tab select Square option. After that you can move the picture within text and pick up font and paragraph size and insert rows and column number: [See on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxUMj.png)